# Dont show space if no add to serve with react-native-google-mobile-ads

Tags: react-native-google-mobile-ads

I'm using react-native-google-mobile-ads to serve mobile ads with react native:
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-google-mobile-ads

The problem I am having, is there is empty space when no ad is being delivered. I'd like there ad space to be completely collapsed (no height).  Is there any way to accomplish this?

I've tried a number of different banner sizes, all with the same issue:

Here is the banner:

```
                        <GAMBannerAd
                            unitId={headerAdUnit}
                            sizes={['FLUID']}
                        />
```